# Override Scrapy output format 'on the fly'

Tags: scrapy

I want to override spider's output format right in the code. I can't modify the settings; I can't change the command line. I want to do it right in the `__init__` method.

Ideally, that new output format should work even if something like `-o /tmp/1.csv` is passed to the spider. But if it's not possible, then pass it.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the case for a pipeline. What exactly do you want to do? Write in a database or something?

Comment: @elias no. It's a complex data pipeline, the output data must be sent to some different data pipelines and it should not be done manually; it should be done automatically on the spider startup. [please don't confuse 'data pipeline' term here, it's not related to the Scrapy Pipeline thing].

Comment: Okay, I've added an answer with a proposal -- does that solve your problem? If not, what's still missing?

Comment: @elias thank you, I wrote a comment there

Answer (score 1):

So, you can put a custom attribute in your spider that sets up how the data should be handled for this spider and create a [Scrapy item pipeline](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) that honors that configuration.

Your spider code would look like:

```
from scrapy import Spider


class MySpider(Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data_destination = self._get_data_destination()

    def _get_data_destination(self):
         # return your dynamically discovered data destination settings here
```

And your [item pipeline](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) would be something like:

```
class MySuperDuperPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        data_destination = getattr(spider, 'data_destination')

        # code to handle item conforming to data destination here...

        return item
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, the main issue is - how can I 'activate' that pipeline automatically? I tried overriding settings dynamically but it didn't work. The only way I could do that is to manually edit the ITEM_PIPELINES settings in settings.py - which is NOT an option in my case. I want to dynamically override that thing, not manually.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, if you use the cutting-edge scrapy (from github's repo) you can use a ``custom_settings`` dict attribute in the spider, but I'm not sure how dynamic you can get with it (it's usually set at class level). You have also other options to pass a setting to the spider without editing settings.py: you can use environment variables or pass the ``-s`` argument to set the setting when you run that spider. If you disclose more details on why you don't want to change a setting in settings.py, it would help to have more ideas.